# Proving $x^\alpha-\alpha x \le 1- \alpha $

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove: $$x^\alpha-\alpha x \le 1- \alpha  \\
> \forall x\ge 0 \ ,  \ 0<\alpha <1$$

It does resamble Lagrange's MVT, in order to get to the RHS, say $\alpha\in[0,1]\Rightarrow \frac{1-\alpha-0^\alpha-\alpha 0}{1-0}=1-\alpha$.

But I'm not sure what to do about the LHS. I always get a negative value in the LHS and we know that the RHS will always be postive but that doesn't really help with proving it...

Edit: maybe define a function: $g(x) = x^\alpha-\alpha x - 1+ \alpha$ Derive it: $g'(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha-1}-\alpha $ but then I get to $x^{\alpha-1}=0$

---

Also, I had two questions when trying to figure this out:

1. Can we use deriviation of both sides of an inequality to prove it ?
2. Can we use limit of both sides of an inequaltiy to prove it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way is to just compute the maximum for the expression on the left via the roots of the derivative, and the monotonicity and convexity/concavity of the function.

Comment: @LutzL Yeah, from plotting it I can see that there's a maximum and the derivtive go through zero but how does that help to solve the inequality ?

Comment: Because then every other function value will be smaller than the value at the maximum, which happens to be the value on the right side.

Comment: Think again about the condition $g'(x)=0$. It is not $x^{α-1}=0$.

Comment: @LutzL But in order to find the maximum of a function we equalize the derivative to zero. Doing this yields: $\alpha x^{\alpha-1}-\alpha=0$.

Comment: Yes, and dividing by $α>0$ yields what?

Comment: @LutzL ah I see my mistake, so we get: $x^{\alpha-1}=1\rightarrow(\alpha-1)\ln x=0 \rightarrow \alpha=1$. This shouldn't be right, because $\alpha<1$...

Comment: And that forces $x$ to be ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^\alpha-\alpha x-\alpha+1$ for $x\geq 0$, where $\alpha<1$, so $f'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}-\alpha$ and $f''(x)=\alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}$. Then $f'(x)=0\Rightarrow x=1$ with $f''(1)=\alpha(\alpha-1)\leq 0$. This implies that $f$ has a local maximum at $x=1$ and so $f(1)=2(1-\alpha)\geq1-\alpha=f(0)$ . Also we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. Since $f$ is continuous for $x\geq 0$, considering above values we see that $f$ has a maximum at $x=1$ and equals $f(1)=2(1-\alpha)$. Therefore we have $f(x)\leq f(1)$ for all $x\geq 0$ and this leads to the desired inequality.

Comment: Use either $f(x)=x^α−αx−(1-α)$ or just short $f(x)=x^α−αx$. It is not clear why your version of the constant is meaningful.

Comment: If my choice of $f$ disturbs you my friend, you can take it like that :). Happy new year.

Comment: Thanks. The best of the new year to You too. But the obvious choices here are to adjust the constant so that either $f(0)=0$ or $f(1)=0$. Am I to assume intentional obfuscation?

Comment: No. You may be right about the short choice of $f$ but it was just an instant effort.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is too easy once one rewrites it as $x^{\alpha} - 1 \leq \alpha(x - 1)$. If $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$, then $f'(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha - 1}$ and then by Mean Value Theorem we have $$x^{\alpha} - 1 = f(x) - f(1) = (x - 1)f'(c) = \alpha(x - 1)c^{\alpha - 1}$$ where $c$ is between $1$ and $x$. Clearly we need to consider cases when $x < 1$ and $x > 1$. For $x = 1$ the result is trivial. Supposing that $x > 1$ we need to ensure that $c^{\alpha - 1} < 1$ which is practically obvious as $1 < c < x$ and $\alpha - 1 < 0$. Same way if $x < 1$ then we need to establish that $c^{\alpha - 1} > 1$ and again this is obvious because then $x < c < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the inequality and writing it as $\;\big(1 + (x-1)\big)^\alpha \le 1 + \alpha (x-1)\;$ reduces it to [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) $\;(1 + t)^r \le 1 + r \,t\,$ for all $\,0 \le r \le 1\;$ and $\;t \ge -1\,$.