# prove: $x^\alpha - \alpha x \le 1-\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

$0 < \alpha  < 1,\forall x \ge 0$
prove: $x^\alpha - \alpha x \le 1-\alpha$

What I did:
We know that: $${x^\alpha } = {e^{\ln ({x^\alpha })}} = {e^{\alpha \ln (x)}}$$
Therefore, we need to prove:

$${e^{\alpha \ln (x)}} < {e^{\ln (1 - \alpha  + \alpha x)}}$$

So, it is suffice to prove:

$$\alpha \ln (x) < \ln (1 - \alpha  - \alpha x)$$

Am I on the right path? I suspect a derivative needed along the way.

Comment: Note that the inequality is not true as written, you need $x^\alpha-\alpha x\le 1-\alpha$ instead.

Comment: It is a duplicate, if I remember correctly. The solution that was given is to define the function $f(x):=...$ and calculate the derivative and investigate the function.

Comment: Same question asked and answered here: (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624850/proving-x-alpha-alpha-x-le-1-alpha)

Comment: It was yesterday(!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $f(x) = x^\alpha - \alpha x$. Then $f'(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} - \alpha.$  For $0\le x \le 1$ you have $f'(x) \ge 0$ and for $x > 1$ you have $f'(x) \le 0$. Hence, there is a a maximum at $x = 1$. Your inequality now follows.

Comment: Indeed, except that one has equality at $x=1$, so the strict inequality that is claimed holds only for $x\ne1$. And while we're in the pedantic corner, your own proof requires some strict inequalities for $f'$ in order to prove the strict inequalities for $f$.

Comment: thanks, can you make it more clear to me: Why does the derivative's sign implies about the inequality?

Comment: The function increases until 1, and decreases thereafter.  Hence, $x = 1$ must be a maximum.

Comment: @ncmathsadist why does showing there's an extramum prove the inequality ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^\alpha$ then $$f''(x)=\alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}\le0$$
hence $f$ is concave and then the its curve is below the tangent line at the point $x=1$ with equation:
$$y=f'(1)(x-1)+f(1)=\alpha(x-1)+1$$
hence
$$x^\alpha-\alpha x\le1-\alpha\quad \text{equality just at}\; x=1$$