# Why does showing a function that is comprised of an inequality has an extremum prove the inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

This is related to [prove: $x^\alpha - \alpha x \le 1-\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625980/prove-x-alpha-alpha-x-le-1-alpha) and [Proving $x^\alpha-\alpha x \le 1- \alpha $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624850/proving-x-alpha-alpha-x-le-1-alpha).

You can see in the answers, they turn the inequality to a function, take the derivative and show it's an extremum, thus proving the inequality.

My question is, why does it mean that the inequality is true ? And can it be generalized to prove every inequality ?

Comment: Finding an extremum amounts to a worst case analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just the definition of extremum.

Suppose $M$ is the maximum (or the largest maximal extremum) of a function $f$, this, **by definition**, means that $\forall x\in \text{dom}(f)(f(x)\leq M)$.

Comment: I see. The function is bounded by it's extremum points. So if there are several different extremum points for the function then the inequality is true for these certain conditions ?

Comment: @GinKin As mentioned, to show $f(x) \le M$, we could attempt to show $M$ is the global maximum for $f(x)$ in the domain.
If $f$ is differentiable and demonstrating $M$ is the global maximum is easy, this provides a convenient way of proving the inequality.  As you may guess, sometimes the $f$ isn't so easy to deal with, hence this method isn't guaranteed to be always useful.

Comment: @GinKin I really dislike the term *extremum* here because it can mean minimal extremum. Let's focus on maximal extrema. A maximal extrema is either local or absolute. If it's absolute, then that's what my answer deals with. I'm assuming that in the linked question, $M$ is an absolute maximum. If you're talking about local maxima, then the inequality will only holdon all elements of the domain of $f$ for the absolute maximum (which is also a local maximum). Does this help?

Comment: Yeah it's more clear now @GitGud. What if the function has only a global minimum ?

Comment: @GinKin If the function has only a global minimum $m$, then the [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(order_theory)) statement holds, that is, $\forall x\in \text{dom}(f)(m\leq f(x))$. Note that $\forall x\in \text{dom}(f)(f(x)\leq K)$ may still hold for a certain $K$, even if $f$ doesn't attain a maximum. Not attaining its maximum does not mean it's not bounded above. As an example consider the [function $x\mapsto -e^{-x^2}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-e%5E%28-x%5E2%29). With $K=0$ the inequality holds, even though $0$ is not attained by $f$.

Comment: So if the function isn't bounded above then the inequality can't be true right ?

Comment: @GinKin Yes, it can't be true by definition of not being bounded above. I might be wrong, by I suspect you're intuitively interpreting some terms such as *bounded above* and *extremum*. All of these are rigorously defined, you should always think about their definitions.