# Show this simple inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $p\in(0,1)$ and $x\in(0,1)$. Show that $1-p+p\cdot x>x^{p}$.

I am able to show this for $p=\frac{1}{2}$ as follows:

$(\frac{1}{2})(1+x)>x^{\frac{1}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow\left(1-x\right)^{2}>0$

I am curious to show this for all $p\in(0,1)$. Any ideas?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/624850/42969

Comment: FWIW I added an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4693222/291201) under the duplicate question pointing out that this is quite literally [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Young-inequality for products. The theorem states that if you have $a, b \geq 0$ real numbers and $p,q > 1$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ (conjugate Hölder exponents). Then \begin{equation}
x \cdot y \leq \frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}
\end{equation} Further, equality holds here if and only if $a^p = b^q$.
If you let $b:=1$ and $q$ the conjugated exponent of $p$:\begin{equation}
x \cdot 1 \leq \frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{1}{q}
\end{equation} Where $\frac{1}{q} = \frac{p-1}{p}$. This is exactly your inequality once you rearrange terms.

Comment: Very nice try, but you need to assume that p>1. In my case, p is a probability so $p\in(0,1)$. The answer is in the link that Martin R. shared above...

Comment: "*This is exactly your inequality*" $\;-\;$ No, this is exactly the opposite inequality, and that's because your $p,q \gt 1$. You can, however, use one of the other forms of [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products) to prove OP's one.